# subdomains on apache with external dns

Tags: server, apache2, dns, vsftpd

First I will describe my setup, after that my problem and last my question for solution.

I have an external DNS server solution (not using DNS on my UBUNTU) where I control all my primary DNS etc. I have my  A records established like this:

```
localhost.itaportalen.dk    127.0.0.1   43200   
itaportalen.dk  5.196.14.205    43200
```

Furthermore I have a `CNAME`:

> .itaportalen.dk    itaportalen.dk  43200

I have an UBUNTU server with apache2 running, and my website is placed in `/var/www/html` - That works like a charm.

I have installed `MySQL` and `VSFTPD` and that works fine as well.

My problem is that I would like to run a multiuser site, and all users should have a `subdomain` to `itaportalen.dk`. When I create a user i.e. "test" that user should have a home directory according to the subdomain `test.itaportalen.dk` with FTP access to only that folder (and subdirectories that user might create).

My questions are as follows:

Where do I place folder for subdomain `test.itaportalen.dk` so that the `CNAME` will point directly to that folder? I can not seem to make this work on UBUNTU and APACHE2

I have `chrooted` my users so that they only see their homefolder (in this case a subdomain) what is the correct way to give them RW access so thay can upload files to their websites?

I know this is pretty basic stuff but I can not seem to make it work on this UBUNTU installation.

Comment: The answer to your question 1 is that you can not do that. For your question 2, you might be able to do it via the apache virtual hosts stuff, but why bother. Why not just do it the way it is already setup to do it. `itaportalen.dk/~test` for user test. Then test would just create and use their public_html directory, once you enable userdir stuff

Comment: Thanks for the comments Doug. Is it specifik to apache on Ubuntu that a * in cname wont redirect to the correct subdomain? Have it running like that under other OS. I am not sure I understand your answer to my second question. Can you elaborate i little bit?

Comment: No, it is not specific to Apace on Ubuntu. DNS cannot direct to a specific folder at an IP address. It can only point to an IP address. I do not know what you are doing under the other OS. Second Q: I was just saying that pretty much by default things are setup such that each user has a default URL already. All you have to do is enable it `sudo a2enmod userdir`.

Comment: Hi Doug and thanks for your reply. I have earlier with succes set a CNAME like this (with correct a records) *.domain.dk On my IIS I just create subdomains on the webserver, and if subdomain is entered in webbrowser, it is directed to the created subdomain on IIS. I do not know if IIS makes some DNS work that I don´t know about.

Answer (score 0):

By default apache is setup for individual users to have their own URL, all you have to do is enable it:

```
sudo a2enmod userdir
```

Then say user test01 access would be via `itaportalen.dk/~test01` and their directory would be `/home/test01/public_html`. However, I gather you don't want to do it that way.

For example, say the user names are test01, test02, test03, test04.
Add A records (or CNAME records, if you prefer) to your DNS zone file:

```
epson-wp2       IN      A       192.168.111.111
s15             IN      A       192.168.111.112
bla             IN      A       192.168.111.112
test01          IN      A       192.168.111.112
test02          IN      A       192.168.111.112
test03          IN      A       192.168.111.112
test04          IN      A       192.168.111.112
s16             IN      A       192.168.111.113
```

All pointing to the same IP address. In your case 5.196.14.205.
Then in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`you will want to create 4 new files. Start by copying the default file:

```
sudo cp 000-default.conf test01.conf
```

Edit the new file like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test01.smythies.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test01

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html/test01>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes
            AllowOverride All
            ...
```

Where I have chosen to have each directory under `/var/www/html`. You do what you want. However, you might need to edit `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, depending on where you locate the directories.
Repeat for the other users. Then enable each virtual host:

```
sudo a2ensite test01
sudo a2ensite test02
sudo a2ensite test03
sudo a2ensite test04
```

Restart:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I did this on my internal test server and it worked as expected. I only used the [Ubuntu Serverguide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html) as a reference.